# WebGui in Fiori

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am implementing List Expiring Contracts app in s/4hana 1610.

While execution, encountering below error

[image: Error]

Issue in Text :

> `http://sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/shells/abap/FioriLaunchpad.html?sap-client=200&sap-language=EN#SalesContract-listExpriringContracts?sap-ui-tech-hint=GUI`

As seen rom above link, the host name and port is missing in it.

Please advise how to maintain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your WebIDE is connected to backend system:

If you have already a backend system configured for your **WebIDE**:
Replace `RefAppsBackend` in file `neo-app.json` with your backend system.

Else:
Goto **SAP WebIDE** and choose **Tools** -> **SAP HANA Cloud Platform Cockpit.** 
In this Cockpit select ‘**Destinations**’ on the left side and then ‘**New Destination**’

**Maintain the following entries:**

```
Name:  RefAppsBackend
Type: HTTP
Description: RefAppsBackend
URL:  Port information of the backend system
Proxy Type: Internet
Authentication: choose an appropriate authentication
```

**Additional Properties:**

```
TrustAll: true
WebIDEEnabled: true
WebIDESystem: RefAppsBackend
WebIDEUsage: odata_abap,ui5_execute_abap,dev_abap
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sunil for your reply.

WebIDE is not configured in our system.

So,the issue is resolved by creating a HTTP Connection(Type H) in SM59 Transaction and mentioning my Launchpad Host Name and Port in Target Host and Service Node.

Regards,

Sayed